# Icons segment triangle

Tags: screen

Segmented triangle with up and down arrows inside triangle appears on the status bar. Can not find what this means. I have checked four different sites.

Answer (score 0):

It is the notificattion for **data saver ON** for OREO update.

Looks something like this.

[image]

Go to settings > connections >  Data Usage > Tap on Data Saver and turn it off

The icon will disapperar. Hope this helps